# ListLogLogPlot origin issues and numerical instability

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, logarithmic-scale

I have the following long functions `f1`and `f2` dependent on parameters `ω` and `g1`:

```
f1 = (1.92`*^8 g1^2)/(10000 (1 + 40000 ω^2) + (400 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 160000 g1^4 + 40004 ω^2 + 160000 ω^4 - 800 g1^2 (-1 + 400 ω^2)) + 200 (-4 ω^2 (1 - 40000 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2) + 20 (1 + 400 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2))) + (96000.` g1^2 (400 + 4 ω^2))/(10000 (1 + 40000 ω^2) + (400 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 160000 g1^4 + 40004 ω^2 + 160000 ω^4 - 800 g1^2 (-1 + 400 ω^2)) + 200 (-4 ω^2 (1 - 40000 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2) + 20 (1 + 400 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2))) + (120200.` (10000 + 200 (20 - 4 ω^2) + (1 + 4 ω^2) (400 + 4 ω^2)))/(10000 (1 + 40000 ω^2) + (400 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 160000 g1^4 + 40004 ω^2 + 160000 ω^4 - 800 g1^2 (-1 + 400 ω^2)) + 200 (-4 ω^2 (1 - 40000 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2) + 20 (1 + 400 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2)))
f2 = (7.68`*^8 g1^2)/(160000 (1 + 40000 ω^2) + (400 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 160000 g1^4 + 40004 ω^2 + 160000 ω^4 - 800 g1^2 (-1 + 400 ω^2)) + 800 (-4 ω^2 (1 - 40000 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2) + 20 (1 + 400 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2))) + (96000.` g1^2 (400 + 4 ω^2))/(160000 (1 + 40000 ω^2) + (400 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 160000 g1^4 + 40004 ω^2 + 160000 ω^4 - 800 g1^2 (-1 + 400 ω^2)) + 800 (-4 ω^2 (1 - 40000 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2) + 20 (1 + 400 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2))) + (120200.` (160000 + 800 (20 - 4 ω^2) + (1 + 4 ω^2) (400 + 4 ω^2)))/(160000 (1 + 40000 ω^2) + (400 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 160000 g1^4 + 40004 ω^2 + 160000 ω^4 - 800 g1^2 (-1 + 400 ω^2)) + 800 (-4 ω^2 (1 - 40000 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2) + 20 (1 + 400 g1^2 + 40000 ω^2)))
```

I intend to find the integral of `f1` and `f2` with respect to `ω` for varying `g1` values. Then doing a Log-Log plot of the resulting integrand against `g1`:

```
test1 = Table[{g1, 1/(2 π)*NIntegrate[Evaluate[f1], {ω, -100, 100}]}, {g1, 0, 150}];
test2 = Table[{g1, 1/(2 π)*NIntegrate[Evaluate[f2], {ω, -100, 100}]}, {g1, 0, 150}];

ListLogLogPlot[{test1, test2}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"test1", "test2"}]
```

I am returned with:
[image]

**First of all** it is important to me that the graph shows that they both start at the same point (which they really do). But it is clear that when the x-axis (`g1`) starts at `1`, the two curves starts at two different `y` values. I was thinking maybe this is because it is not possible to show `Log[0]`. I tried to remedy the issue by picking a `g1` value close to 0 and replot it:

[image]
Clearly they do start from the same value when `g1=0.01` but there appears to be a kink around `g1=1`. In general, I just want a Log-Log graph that shows that both curves starts at the same point when the x-axis is `0` How should I approach this?

**Second of all**, it appears that beyond `g1=100` the curve drops suddenly to about `0.01`. I think it might be numerical instabilities but I'm not sure what's going on here. If it were numerics, I should have had warnings but I didn't see any. What is going on here?

Comment: I notice I can change the position of the "kink" at the right end of your graphs by changing your `{ω, -100, 100}` to `{ω, -80, 80}` or to `{ω, -140, 140}`. There are some warnings about convergence, but the "kink" appears to track that ω bound exactly. Maybe this is enough of a hint to figure out why the "kink" is there.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for the help. I still need to show both curves to be starting from the same value smoothly in the Log plot. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't be certain about the instability, but `Plot3D[f1, {ω, -100, 100}, {g1, 0, 150}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]` seems to show that your expressions appear to blow up for certain values of g1 and ω. I'm guessing that is because of your large complicated denominators going to zero. `Simplify[Solve[ Denominator[Simplify[f1]] == 0, {ω, g1}]]` might give you some hints about why that is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a smoother result by calculating the integrals analytically (though not in closed form) first:

```
aux1[g1_, \[Omega]_] = Integrate[f1, \[Omega]];
aux2[g1_, \[Omega]_] = Integrate[f2, \[Omega]];

int1[g1_] = aux1[g1, 100] - aux1[g1, -100];
int2[g1_] = aux2[g1, 100] - aux2[g1, -100];

LogLogPlot[{1/(2 \[Pi]) int1[g], 1/(2 \[Pi]) int2[g]}, {g, 0.01, 150}]
```

[image]